# Authoratitive server for Enemy AI

Tags: mmo

I am writting a real time game which contains Enemy AI
I need write Enemy AI on server to send action( move, attack, .. ) to clients?
or any way to do that?
If i write Enemy AI on client? how to be authoritative enemy's actions?

Comment: Given the mmo tag, yes, the server handles enemy AI. Do you have a concrete problem you are having trouble to solve?

Comment: i am using Photon Engine, i want to know some Physic engines which support move, collision, .. written by C#

Comment: Odd you ask about a physic engine in a question about enemy AI. I suppose you have your reasons to want C#... I do not have any to recommend (heck, I do not even know if you want 2D or 3D or what sort of features you need). In fact, it is not rare that people who are not using a full blown engine (e.g. Unity3D) will spin their own. Asking for tools is off-topic in this site anyway. However, I am sure you can find a few if you [search](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=C%23%20physics%20engine).

Comment: Voting to close this as off topic because `i want to know some Physic engines which support move, collision` makes it sound like a software recommendation question.

Comment: You can't write it on the client. The server needs to handle it and just send the data such as AI position, notification that it attacked etc. Nobody can tell you how to do that in your engine.

Comment: I see that you are looking for a Physics Engine..... The best thing I could find is Bullet. Bullet is written in C++, but there is a C# port and you can easily use it in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enemy AI is one of those things which should always be handled on the server.

Remember that anything which happens on the client can be manipulated by a hacked client. If you let the client handle enemies, the client can just claim that the ultimate raid boss just committed suicide and dropped the rarest item in the game.

But even if you assume that all your clients play fairly (you can't), that you can just slap an anti cheat tool on it and it will fix any cheating problems (it won't) or that you can detect cheating heuristically (will cause you more problems than it solves), you still need to deal with synchronization problems. What do you do if multiple clients fight the same monster and they come to different conclusions about how the fight turned out? Due to network latency, this is quite likely to happen.

Comment: thanks, i see. so, i need a physic engine on server which support c#

Comment: @Lenon When this answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark-icon next to it.